# The Probability that the sum of binomial R.V is even?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

i got two independent  binomial Random Variables, 
such that:

$X$~$Bin(99,0.5)$

$Y$~$Bin(100,0.5)$

i need to calc' the probability that $X+Y$ is even.
so i started to do:

$P("X + Y"$ is even ) = P($X,Y$ is even) + P($X,Y$ is odd)

$X,Y$ are  independent, so it's easy to use the multiplication of probabilities

but i'm stuck, how can i figure this probability:

$P(Y= 2K) = \sum^{50}_{i=1}\binom{100}{2k}\cdot \frac{1}{2^{100}}$

?

Comment: Did you mean $\sum^{50}_{\color{red}{k=1}}\binom{100}{2k}\cdot \frac{1}{2^{100}}$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- $Z:=X+Y\sim\text{Bin}(199,0.5)$
- $Z$ is even iff $199-Z$ is odd.
- $Z$ and $199-Z$ have the same distribution.

---

Actually my answer is not really an answer to the question you pose: "how can i figure this probability...". It provides a route that makes it unnecessary to "figure this probability".

Answer (score 1):

A binomial random variable with $p=\frac{1}{2}$ always takes odd and even values with the same probability. This is a straightforward consequence of the identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k = (1-1)^n = \color{red}{0}.$$